# Value of i in loop keeps getting overridden even after changing explicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, data-structures

This code is for reference. Working on a code with a similar implementation.
I wanted to override the value of i inside the loop:

```
def function():
    num = 10
    for i in range(num):
        print(i)
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            i = i + 2
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

The actual output fro the above code :
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I expected that the value of i will be updated inside the loop, since I have different values to add to i depending on the condition, whereas it was getting overridden at the start of the loop to be in sequence.
Can anyone explain how can i stop this? I wanted to update the value of i inside the loop logic.

Comment: You *are* updating the value of `i`, but you never use the updated value. The `for` loop updates `i` itself at the start of every iteration overwriting your own update.

Comment: And it looks you may need different kind of loop (i.e. while loop) or completely different code pattern/construct - it's unclear what you actually want to achieve with this.

Comment: Maybe you can also show us the desired outputs in this case?  `num = 10`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, your loop variable keeps getting reinitialized. If you want to run a loop without getting the variable reinitialized, you have to use while loop.

```
def function():
    num = 10
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        print(i)
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            i = i + 2
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: I suspect this might not what the OP wants ... but the description is not clear.   Running this only will yield - `0  2 4 6 8`. (each one line)?

Answer (score 0):

In for loop, once the variable is decided, the value doesn't change, ot changes only based on the updating value of range. You can change the value only in case of while loop. Try using while loop. Use this:

```
while i<10: #num

      print(i)

     if i%2==0:

          i+=2

      else:

          i+=1​
```

Check for indentation errors, I've written it on my own